# Extract lines from a file based on a range that fall within the range from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with ca. 17000 rows for which I need to extract rows based on values from columns 2 and 3 (which are the start and end of a range):

file_1.txt

```
NC_018723.3 88839   102219
NC_018723.3 156206  160651
NC_018723.3 160885  165615
NC_018723.3 178410  191119
NC_018723.3 226179  242932
NC_018723.3 243929  310071
NC_018723.3 384020  413475
```

I have a second file, also with ranges:

file_2.txt

```
8410001 8420000
8420001 8430000
28550001    28560000
28560001    28570000
111910001   111920000
111920001   111930000
209310001   209320000
209320001   209330000
209330001   209340000
```

I'm looking for a way to extract rows from file_1.txt for which the range of column 2 and 3 fall within the ranges of file_2.txt.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! I see you have tagged this with `awk`, which is a very good tool for the job. Which part of this is giving you trouble? Have you tried anything? Did it work? How did it fail? It really helps if you show us your attempts so we don't try the same, bad solutions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify if the comparison should be on a line by line basis or the values in file1 compared to all ranges in file 2, and add the expected output given your posted sample input plus your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you.

Comment: Also, are these really the actual files or are you working with something different? Could these be GTF and bed files, for example?

Answer (score 0):

[TXR Lisp](https://www.nongnu.org/txr) solution.

First, `file_1.txt` is augmented with some ranges cases that actually fall into the ranges in `file_2.txt`:

```
NC_018723.3 88839   102219
NC_018723.3 156206  160651
NC_018723.3 160885  165615
NC_018723.3 178410  191119
NC_018723.3 226179  242932
NC_018723.3 243929  310071
NC_018723.3 384020  413475

FOO_1 8420001 8430000
FOO_2 8430000 8440000
FOO_3 8430000 8440000
FOO_4 209310001 209320001
FOO_5 209310001 209320000
FOO_6     209310002 209320000
FOO_7 209310002 209319999
```

Run:

```
$ txr soln.tl 
FOO_1 8420001 8430000
FOO_5 209310001 209320000
FOO_6 209310002 209320000
FOO_7 209310002 209319999
```

Code in `soln.tl`:

```
(defvarl rtree [tree nil to])

(defun add-range (tree range)
  (tree-insert tree range))

(defun lookup-range (tree range)
  (let* ((iter (tree-begin tree (from range)))
         (node (tree-next iter))
         (found (if node (key node))))
    (if (and found
             (>= (from range) (from found))
             (<= (to range) (to found)))
      found)))

(awk
  (:inputs "file_2.txt")
  (t (fconv i i) (add-range rtree [f 0]..[f 1])))

(awk
  (:inputs "file_1.txt")
  (t (fconv - i i)
     (if (lookup-range rtree [f 1]..[f 2])
       (prn))))
```

The approach here is to use a binary search tree to store the ranges from `file_2.txt`.

TXR Lisp has a range type: a kind of binary cell with accessors `from` and `to`. We can explore this at the REPL:

```
1> 10..20
#R(10 20)
2> (typeof *1)
range
3> (from *1)
10
4> (to *1)
20
```

In the `soln.tl` program, the expression `[tree nil to]` constructs a new binary search tree. The `nil` makes it empty, and `to` is the key function. Notice that it's the function which accesses the `to` field of a range. We are going to put range objects into this tree, and they will be keyed on their `to` field.

The `lookup-range` function is the most complicated. Given an input range, it determines whether the range is contained within a range stored in the tree. It uses `tree-begin` to start walking the tree in order, but ignoring all nodes whose key (i.e. `to` field) is lower than the `from` field of the input range. In other words, we are looking for the node with the lowest `to` field which is greater than the `from` field of our search range.

Once we find that node, we apply a simple overlap test to confirm it.

After the function definitions, there are two `(awk ..)` expressions. The first `awk` processes `file_2.txt` to populate the tree hash. The `fconv` Awk operator is used to convert the fields to integers, and `[f 0]..[f 1]` constructs a range object from them.

The second `{awk ...)` job processes `file_1.txt`, doing a lookup on the ranges, printing those records which match.

Because a balanced binary tree is used for the ranges, `file_2.txt` could be large.

Whitespace is not preserved in the output, because we modified the fields with `fconv`. In Awk, when you assign to a field, it recalculates the record image by catenating the fields with the output field separator.

To preserve the whitespace, we can change the second `awk` like this. We introduce a local variable `recsave` and use that to save the value of `rec`, the record (like `$0` in Classic Awk).

```
(awk
  (:inputs "file_1.txt")
  (:let recsave)
  (t (set recsave rec)
     (fconv - i i)
     (if (lookup-range rtree [f 1]..[f 2])
       (prn recsave))))
```